# Too few arguments to function Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\PersistentCollection::__construct()

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

When sending requests to a running api-platform interface of a Symfony (v6.1.12, php8.2.1) application from an ubuntu instance (5.15.0-60-generic) within docker (v20.10.22) similar to this one:

http://localhost/api/posts?limit=20

I keep retrieving server errors 500 with an error message stating `Too few arguments to function Doctrine\\ODM\\MongoDB\\PersistentCollection::__construct(), 0 passed in \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/doctrine\/mongodb-odm\/lib\/Doctrine\/ODM\/MongoDB\/PersistentCollection\/DefaultPersistentCollectionFactory.php on line 16 and exactly 3 expected`
.

I receive this error message for every request against the api-platform from within my docker container running on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

My composer config reads:

```
composer show | grep 'symfony\|doctrine'
dama/doctrine-test-bundle            v6.7.5    Symfony bundle to isolate doctrine database tests and improve test performance
doctrine/annotations                 1.14.3    Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       2.2.0     PHP Doctrine Cache library is a popular cache implementation that supports many different drivers suc...
doctrine/collections                 1.8.0     PHP Doctrine Collections library that adds additional functionality on top of PHP arrays.
doctrine/common                      3.4.3     PHP Doctrine Common project is a library that provides additional functionality that other Doctrine p...
doctrine/data-fixtures               1.6.3     Data Fixtures for all Doctrine Object Managers
doctrine/dbal                        3.6.0     Powerful PHP database abstraction layer (DBAL) with many features for database schema introspection a...
doctrine/deprecations                v1.0.0    A small layer on top of trigger_error(E_USER_DEPRECATED) or PSR-3 logging with options to disable all...
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             2.8.3     Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle    3.4.2     Symfony DoctrineFixturesBundle
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle  3.2.2     Symfony DoctrineMigrationsBundle
doctrine/event-manager               1.2.0     The Doctrine Event Manager is a simple PHP event system that was built to be used with the various Do...
doctrine/inflector                   2.0.6     PHP Doctrine Inflector is a small library that can perform string manipulations with regard to upper/...
doctrine/instantiator                1.5.0     A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                       2.1.0     PHP Doctrine Lexer parser library that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/migrations                  3.6.0     PHP Doctrine Migrations project offer additional functionality on top of the database abstraction lay...
doctrine/mongodb-odm                 2.4.3     PHP Doctrine MongoDB Object Document Mapper (ODM) provides transparent persistence for PHP objects to...
doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle          4.5.2     Symfony Doctrine MongoDB Bundle
doctrine/orm                         2.14.1    Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
doctrine/persistence                 3.1.4     The Doctrine Persistence project is a set of shared interfaces and functionality that the different D...
doctrine/sql-formatter               1.1.3     a PHP SQL highlighting library
friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle     v6.2.0    Elasticsearch PHP integration for your Symfony project using Elastica
gedmo/doctrine-extensions            v3.11.1   Doctrine behavioral extensions
stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle      v1.7.1    Integration of the gedmo/doctrine-extensions with Symfony
symfony/apache-pack                  v1.0.1    A pack for Apache support in Symfony
symfony/asset                        v5.4.19   Manages URL generation and versioning of web assets such as CSS stylesheets, JavaScript files and ima...
symfony/browser-kit                  v6.2.5    Simulates the behavior of a web browser, allowing you to make requests, click on links and submit for...
symfony/cache                        v6.2.5    Provides extended PSR-6, PSR-16 (and tags) implementations
symfony/cache-contracts              v3.2.0    Generic abstractions related to caching
symfony/config                       v6.2.5    Helps you find, load, combine, autofill and validate configuration values of any kind
symfony/console                      v6.2.5    Eases the creation of beautiful and testable command line interfaces
symfony/css-selector                 v6.2.5    Converts CSS selectors to XPath expressions
symfony/dependency-injection         v6.1.12   Allows you to standardize and centralize the way objects are constructed in your application
symfony/deprecation-contracts        v3.2.0    A generic function and convention to trigger deprecation notices
symfony/doctrine-bridge              v5.4.19   Provides integration for Doctrine with various Symfony components
symfony/doctrine-messenger           v6.2.5    Symfony Doctrine Messenger Bridge
symfony/dom-crawler                  v6.2.5    Eases DOM navigation for HTML and XML documents
symfony/dotenv                       v6.2.5    Registers environment variables from a .env file
symfony/error-handler                v6.2.5    Provides tools to manage errors and ease debugging PHP code
symfony/event-dispatcher             v6.2.5    Provides tools that allow your application components to communicate with each other by dispatching e...
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts   v3.2.0    Generic abstractions related to dispatching event
symfony/expression-language          v5.4.19   Provides an engine that can compile and evaluate expressions
symfony/filesystem                   v6.2.5    Provides basic utilities for the filesystem
symfony/finder                       v6.2.5    Finds files and directories via an intuitive fluent interface
symfony/flex                         v2.2.5    Composer plugin for Symfony
symfony/framework-bundle             v6.0.19   Provides a tight integration between Symfony components and the Symfony full-stack framework
symfony/http-client                  v6.2.6    Provides powerful methods to fetch HTTP resources synchronously or asynchronously
symfony/http-client-contracts        v3.2.0    Generic abstractions related to HTTP clients
symfony/http-foundation              v6.2.6    Defines an object-oriented layer for the HTTP specification
symfony/http-kernel                  v6.1.12   Provides a structured process for converting a Request into a Response
symfony/mailer                       v6.1.11   Helps sending emails
symfony/maker-bundle                 v1.48.0   Symfony Maker helps you create empty commands, controllers, form classes, tests and more so you can f...
symfony/messenger                    v6.2.5    Helps applications send and receive messages to/from other applications or via message queues
symfony/mime                         v6.1.11   Allows manipulating MIME messages
symfony/monolog-bridge               v5.4.19   Provides integration for Monolog with various Symfony components
symfony/monolog-bundle               v3.8.0    Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/options-resolver             v6.2.5    Provides an improved replacement for the array_replace PHP function
symfony/password-hasher              v6.2.5    Provides password hashing utilities
symfony/phpunit-bridge               v6.2.5    Provides utilities for PHPUnit, especially user deprecation notices management
symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme       v1.27.0   Symfony polyfill for intl's grapheme_* functions
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn            v1.27.0   Symfony polyfill for intl's idn_to_ascii and idn_to_utf8 functions
symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer     v1.27.0   Symfony polyfill for intl's Normalizer class and related functions
symfony/polyfill-mbstring            v1.27.0   Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php72               v1.27.0   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.2+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php73               v1.27.0   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.3+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php80               v1.27.0   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php81               v1.27.0   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.1+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/property-access              v5.4.19   Provides functions to read and write from/to an object or array using a simple string notation
symfony/property-info                v5.4.19   Extracts information about PHP class' properties using metadata of popular sources
symfony/proxy-manager-bridge         v5.4.19   Provides integration for ProxyManager with various Symfony components
symfony/routing                      v6.2.5    Maps an HTTP request to a set of configuration variables
symfony/security                     2.0.6     Symfony Security Component
symfony/security-bundle              v5.4.20   Provides a tight integration of the Security component into the Symfony full-stack framework
symfony/security-core                v5.4.19   Symfony Security Component - Core Library
symfony/security-csrf                v6.2.5    Symfony Security Component - CSRF Library
symfony/security-guard               v5.4.19   Symfony Security Component - Guard
symfony/security-http                v5.4.20   Symfony Security Component - HTTP Integration
symfony/serializer                   v5.4.19   Handles serializing and deserializing data structures, including object graphs, into array structures...
symfony/service-contracts            v2.5.2    Generic abstractions related to writing services
symfony/stopwatch                    v6.2.5    Provides a way to profile code
symfony/string                       v6.2.5    Provides an object-oriented API to strings and deals with bytes, UTF-8 code points and grapheme clust...
symfony/translation-contracts        v3.2.0    Generic abstractions related to translation
symfony/twig-bridge                  v6.1.11   Provides integration for Twig with various Symfony components
symfony/twig-bundle                  v5.4.19   Provides a tight integration of Twig into the Symfony full-stack framework
symfony/validator                    v5.4.19   Provides tools to validate values
symfony/var-dumper                   v6.2.5    Provides mechanisms for walking through any arbitrary PHP variable
symfony/var-exporter                 v6.2.5    Allows exporting any serializable PHP data structure to plain PHP code
symfony/web-link                     v6.2.5    Manages links between resources
symfony/webpack-encore-bundle        v1.16.1   Integration with your Symfony app & Webpack Encore!
symfony/yaml                         v6.2.5    Loads and dumps YAML files
```

I had to **downgrade** the doctrine/mongodb-odm - bundle from **version 2.4.3 to version 2.3.1 ** in order to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade the doctrine/mongodb-odm - bundle from **version 2.4.3 to version 2.3.3** in order to fix this error.

I did so by executing

`composer require "doctrine/mongodb-odm:<2.4.0" --with-all-dependencies`

Which locks the dependency to a fixed version. As soon as the mongodb-odm - bundle has been fixed by doctrine, this version lock should be removed again.